# How to access AuthErrorCode (without auth/ prefix) in Firebase JS SDK

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wonder how to access the correct error code in firebase (v10).

```
public resetPassword(email: string, actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings): Promise<void> {
  return sendPasswordResetEmail(this.auth, email, actionCodeSettings);
}

public async resetPassword(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.resetPassword(this.email, this.actionCodeSettings);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof FirebaseError && error.message === AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_EMAIL) {
        // never hit because AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_EMAIL = "auth/invalid-email" & error.message = "INVALID_EMAIL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code returns the following response, when I enter an email that is not in firebase.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Firebase `AuthErrorCodes` ([link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/60e4a07d2c89b5ea473f903a942aabab03050fa5/packages/auth/src/core/errors.ts#L497)) has those codes, but with `auth/` prefix. I want to access the codes from `AuthErrorCode` ([link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/60e4a07d2c89b5ea473f903a942aabab03050fa5/packages/auth/src/core/errors.ts#L30)) but they are internal. Any idea how to safely catch this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error code (e.g. `auth/invalid-email`) is in the thrown error, not in the response. So the following just works:

```
if (error instanceof FirebaseError && error.code === AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_EMAIL) {
  console.log("catched");
}
```

Another obvious solution would have been to match against the string (e.g. `INVALID_EMAIL`), but I wanted to avoid that.